# Is there a way to format output more specifically in C++?

Tags: c++, output, iomanip

When I assign the value in `setprecision()` to `1`

and

`{ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 0, 1, 1 }`

is inputted as values, MyProgrammingLab says I have an error in the output for `average`. My program displays `1.2` when it should display `1.25`.

So when I change the value in `setprecision()` to `2`

and

`{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 }`

is inputted as values, MyProgrammingLab says again I have an error in the output for `average`. My program displays `6.50` when it should only display `6.5`.

What can I do so that `average` is outputted correctly in both instances?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {

   // Creating int variable to hold total 
   double total = 0;

   // Array
   double value[12];

   // Loop to prompt user for each value
   for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      cout << "Enter value: ";  
      cin >> value[i];
    }

   // Loop to add all values together
   for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
       total += value[i];

   // Creating a double to hold average
   double average;

   // Formatting output
   cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

   // Calculating average
   average = total / 12;

   // Displaying average
   cout << "Average value: " << average << endl;

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "MyProgrammingLab says I have an error in the output for average"? Do you mean it is not displaying like you expect it to, or what is the specific error that it is giving you? Also, 6.50 is correct for when you set the precision to 2. Are you hoping that it will drop off trailing 0's?

Comment: Try removing fixed. If you then set the precision to 2 it would display two digits after the decimal point only if they are significant.

Comment: @A.Hristov Removing fixed didn't work

Comment: @Shaavin Yes, it's not displaying like I expect it to. It's fine on my compiler, but MyProgrammingLab expects it in the way I described it. And yes, for that instance I am hoping that it will drop off the trailing 0. The problem is that I need to write something applicable to the first case as well.

Comment: What would `printf("%f", ...)` print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a little helper function that formats the string the way you want. I've put comments in my code to explain.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string RemoveTrailingZero(double value)
{
    //Convert to precision of two digits after decimal point
    std::ostringstream out;
    out << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << value;
    std::string str = out.str();

    //Remove trailing '0'
    str.erase(str.find_last_not_of('0') + 1, std::string::npos);

    //Remove '.' if no digits after it
    if (str.find('.') == str.size() - 1)
    {
        str.pop_back();
    }
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << RemoveTrailingZero(1.25) << std::endl;
    std::cout << RemoveTrailingZero(6.50) << std::endl;
    std::cout << RemoveTrailingZero(600.0) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1.25
6.5
600
```